# Migration handling unsupported types

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb, database-migration

I already have a database setup and I would like to create migration(s) from an empty db to current state.

How do I handle unsupported types (like Point) by Laravel migration?

Only solution I could think of was using `DB::statement` and writing raw SQL. Is there any better way?

Also, is there any converter from an existing DB to Laravel migration that properly handles these unsupported types?

Comment: Can you explain about unsupported types ?

Comment: @SagarGautam Please look at available column types: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations

Comment: @metalcamp So, You have other type of column data

Comment: @SagarGautam exactly.

Comment: I think @ThomasMoors is on right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package that can do this for you: https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-nomad/

It has a function with this signature:

```
 public function passthru($realType, $column, $definition = null)
    {
        return $this->addColumn('passthru', $column, compact('realType', 'definition'));
    }
```

That is used like

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->passthru('citext', 'name');
            $table->passthru('citext', 'title')->nullable();
            $table->passthru('string', 'email', 'varchar(255)')->unique();
            $table->passthru('string', 'password')->definition('varchar(60)');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

It extends the BaseBlueprint class and uses the function `addColumn`
https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_addColumn